# 'bID' cannot be null error on Concrete5 Block

Tags: concrete5

I am trying to create a new block and my db.xml looks like this:

```
<schema
xmlns="http://www.concrete5.org/doctrine-xml/0.5"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.concrete5.org/doctrine-xml/0.5 http://concrete5.github.io/doctrine-xml/doctrine-xml-0.5.xsd">

<table name="btAssociationManagers">
    <field name="bID" type="integer">
        <unsigned/>
        <key/>
        <notnull/>
    </field>
    <field name="name" type="text"></field>
    <field name="association_name" type="text"></field>
<field name="description" type="text"></field>
</table>
</schema>
```

and in my controller I have this property:

```
protected $btTable = "btAssociationManagers";
```

I can install my block without any problem, but when I try to put it somewhere in page I receive this error:

An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO btAssociationManagers (bID, name, association_name, description) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)' with params [null, "dfsdfg", "gfhjfghjgfhj", "ghgj"]: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'bID' cannot be null

I tried to solve it in so many ways but it didn't work.
Can someone help please?

Best Regards

Comment: If you want to take a modification of the `db.xml` file into account you have to uninstall and reinstall the block. Did you do it?

Comment: I know it and I droped the table each time, still it didnt make any sense. Now I gave up and solved it in another way. thank you

Answer (score 1):

Is this 5.6+ or 5.7+ (or even 5.8 beta)? It looks like your field types are not really in keeping with how Concrete5 does things, at least in 5.6 in these docs http://legacy-documentation.concrete5.org/tutorials/creating-and-working-with-db-xml-files

Instead of `type="integer"` it's just `type="I"`

In the top of the db.xml document you've got a lot of extra going on up there... I've never had to specify more than just:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<schema version="0.3">
<table name="btMyTableName">
    <field name="bID" type="I"><key /><unsigned /></field>
</table>
</schema>
```

Comment: My system is 5.7, I tried this version of cml too but it didn't work. Finnally I gave up and wrote that block clearly from the beginning. My db.xml still looks same but however it worked. thanks for your help.